# Splitting Field of $x^3-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

What is the splitting field of $p(x)=x^3-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_4$?

$\mathbb{F}_2=\{0,1\}$ seems also to be the splitting field of $p(x)$

$p(0)=0$

$p(1)=0$

Which one I choose? $\mathbb{F}_4$ or $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: Do you know how to factor the polynomial $x^3-x$?

Comment: Sure, $x^3-x=x(x^2-1)=x(x+1)(x-1)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer has to be an extension of $\mathbb{F}_4$, and therefore it cannot be $\mathbb{F}_2$. But, in $\mathbb{F}_4$,$$x^3-x=x(x^2+1)=x(x+1)^2$$and therefore the answer is $\mathbb{F}_4$.

Comment: Why $x^2-1=x^2+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_4$? I know $\mathbb{F}_4$ elements are $\{0,1,\alpha,\overline{\alpha}\}$.

Comment: Because $\mathbb{F}_4$ is a field with characteristic $2$. Therefore, in $\mathbb{F}_4$ we have $1=-1$.

Comment: Is this because $\mathbb{F}_4$ is an extension of $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: Yes. An extension of a field always has the same characteristic as that field.

Comment: Could you give me a simple definition of characteristic of a finite field? Maybe with an example?

Comment: The characteristic of a finite field $F$ is the smallest natural number $n$ such that$$\overbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}^{n\text{ times}}=0.$$

Comment: If the problem was finding the splitting field over $\mathbb{F}_2$? Does the answer remain the same? I can't understand why I can't splitting over $\mathbb{F}_2$, I've got his roots into $\mathbb{F}_2$ and I can write it like $x(x+1)(x-1)=x(x+1)^2$ that are 3 linear terms.

Comment: If the polynomial was an element of $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$, then the answer would be $\mathbb{F}_2$. But you wrote “over $\mathbb{F}_4$” in your question.

Comment: Yeah sure, it was an hypotesis. Thanks